# How to disable GCC warning "Wstack-usage" temporarily?

Tags: c, pragma, gcc-warning

I am trying to compile a project that imports this BiTStream [file](https://github.com/gfto/bitstream/blob/master/mpeg/psi/descs_print.h).

GCC outputs the following error:

> warning: stack usage might be unbounded [-Wstack-usage=]

Indeed, in the compilation command line (generated via CMake) I have:

> -Wstack-usage=2048

I want to keep this warning for the rest of the project but disable it for this specific file.

I have checked [GCC Warnings options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and [GCC diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) and tried:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-default"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstack-usage"

#include <bitstream/mpeg/psi/descs_print.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But GCC still complains:

> warning: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind
>   [-Wpragmas]
>
> #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wstack-usage"

Note that the other warnings are correctly disabled.

Is there a specific synatx for `Wstack-usage` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clue is in the error message:

> warning: stack usage might be unbounded [-Wstack-usage=]

Thus, the #pragma you need to use is:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstack-usage="
```